# ng-repeat creates element without innerHTML

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I made a GET request, got back an array of objects. Used ng-repeat to create a table with the response. The number of rows in the table matched the number of objects, but the value of the object property (message.id) was not visible on the table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="testApp">
    <div>
        <table >
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top">
            <div ng-controller="msgCntrl">
            <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>User</th>
                      <th>Message</th>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr ng-repeat="message in names">
                        <td> {{message.user}}</td>
                        <td> {{message.content}} </td>      
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
        </td>
          
        <td class="col-md-3" style="width:25%;padding-left:40px;vertical-align: top">
            <div ng-controller="otherController">
               <!-- this POST data to the application-->
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>    
    </div>
</div>
<script>
        var app = angular.module("testApp", []);            
        app.controller("msgCntrl", function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.names = null;
            $http.get('/api/message/').
                success(function(data) {
                    $scope.names = data.objects;
                    console.log($scope.names);// Printed the response properly
            });       
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is how the table looks like. The text is not visible]

Console log:

[image]

Comment: could you please share the content of `$scope.names` too from the `console` ?

Comment: Try with  $scope.names = [];

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems to be ok but make sure that

```
     <td> {{message.user}}</td>
     <td> {{message.content}} </td>
```

The message has property name user and content and  user and content have some value and please share the console.log as well

Comment: Individual content of object log please

Comment: One more thing i didn't see user property in log

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us what you get on:

```
console.log($scope.names);
```

Maybe you need to declare your controller in your HTMl tag like:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="msgCntrl">
         ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it can help.